# Performing Suitability Analysis using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.4, workflow, suitability-analysis

I'm new to GIS (using ArcGIS 10.4) and stuck on the following problem: I need a way to find ideal locations for supermarkets that will service the most people possible based on proximity (as the crow flies).

To solve this I used Location-Allocation Analysis (Network Analyst Extension) with the problem type "maximise coverage".

Comment: Before going through the workflow -have you thought about what your measure for successful placement of a grocery store would be? That is, would it serve X amount of people, or would it serve Y area of low income area?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user please take the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). Unfortunately, this question may not be specific enough for our "Focused question / Best answer" model. Several possibilities present themselves, but most are of an iterative nature, depending on whether the question is the :minimum number" or the *locations* of the minimum number (which may be an infinite set). Also of concern is the way distance is calculated (crow-fly or linear model)

Comment: Thanks so much for your replies! @vince I have edited the comment to try and improve the clarity as much as I can, I have now taken the tour but I'm not quite sure how to ask the question differently sorry. I need to find the minimum number but I assumed that to find the minimum number the location would be necessary as one supermarket could serve multiple food deserts depending on its location, I hope this makes sense and thanks a lot for replying.

Comment: @DPSSpatial successful placement of the grocery stores only depends on eradicating the food deserts (which already take into account income) so the grocery stores do not have to serve a specific amount of people, the only goal is to provide enough supermarkets so that every person in a low income area is in a 1 mile proximity to one. Thanks so much for your reply!

Comment: @Jess do you have a population dataset you could use to intersect with the buffer/service area of the proposed grocery store? Or are you more concerned with simply covering your area with the 1mi buffers of the grocery stores you place?

Comment: @DPSSpatial I think the latter, I've already used a population dataset to intersect with the buffer area of the supermarkets to determine food desert populations. I have several discrete food desert areas (defined as census block groups) that are near to each other that would be within the buffer area of a single new grocery store which is why I am finding it difficult to come up with optimal locations and a minimum number. Thanks, I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @Jess well if you're toolset is ArcGIS then you should create a model that will use the proposed grocery store points as the input, buffer them by 1 mi, then create an output buffer shapefile / feature class (likely in the same folder as your proposed grocery store) . run the model once, add the result buffer to your map. You should be able to add a grocery store in an edit session, save the edits (stay in an edit session), run the model, and the buffer output should update in your map and you'll be able to see where the areas cover. Test that out for starters...

Comment: Once you have tested these suggestions, if you still need help, please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with what you have tried and where you are stuck so that it can be re-opened for further processing.

Comment: Do you have access to the Network Analyst extension? If so, and if the only condition for your new grocery stores is to service the grocery deserts, you may be able to achieve this using a Location-Allocation layer.

Comment: @Adam thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed, I used the location allocation layer with maximise coverage as the problem type.

Comment: Perfect! Maybe you could refine your question and provide the solution as an answer so others can learn from it.